# How RESTeasy solves @Path conflict

Tags: java, resteasy

Consider the code above

```
@Path("a")
@Produces("text/plain")
public class A {

    @GET
    @Path("a")
    public String getA() {
        return "a";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("a")
    public String getB() {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

Requesting http://host/a/a i always get "b".

What is the strategy to select the appropiated method ?
Any way to get informed about multiple paths to diferent resources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further edited in light of the comment

I don't know of any reporting tool within RESTEasy that offers a list of duplicated matching patterns across a range of annotated service classes. However, you could approach this problem using one of the following methods:

1. grep and awk the source code for @Path to generate a sortable list of path expressions
2. Use an [AnnotationReader implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/jaxb-impl/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader.java.java-doc.htm) to scan over your classpath as part of a unit test and have it detect duplicated regex patterns.

---

Edited to better target the question

RESTEasy uses a [regex based system for paths](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings) and selects the most closely matching pattern. In the event of a collision the last one matched is used.

Comment: Yes i get that clear, but consider a 200 classes WS or using classes from a binary library. You must control the @Path annotation manually. The compiler won´t get the duplicates. I'm curious what the spec says, but i cannot find that issue.

Comment: Updated answer in light of comment

Comment: @PeterMmm How did you get on with your solution to this? If you reached an answer it would be useful to post it for others to benefit.